# Why this EditText value's checker work but after correcting the text inside Edittex, getting error

Tags: android, input, android-edittext

In my code I've a EditText which accept values between 100 till 1000. i create a custom Toast consists of several layers like gif and other as below:

```
    InputStream stream_loader_gif = null;
    try
    {
        stream_loader_gif = getAssets().open("loader.gif");
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    final GifDecoderView gif_view = new GifDecoderView( getBaseContext(), stream_loader_gif);
```

and here's the whole checker :

```
            if( (TextUtils.isEmpty( et_height.getText().toString())) ||  (Float.parseFloat(et_height.getText().toString())<100.0) || (Float.parseFloat(et_height.getText().toString())>1000.0) )
            {
                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                View layout = inflater.inflate( R.layout.warning_toast_rebar, (ViewGroup) findViewById (R.id.warning_toast_rebar_xml) );

                LinearLayout gifPresenter = (LinearLayout) layout.findViewById(R.id.gifView_at_toast_at_rebar);
                gifPresenter.addView(gif_view);

                TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text_at_toast_at_rebar);
                text.setText("Height Must be Between 100 - 1000");
                text.setTextSize(16);
                text.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

                Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
                toast.setDuration(30000);
                toast.setView(layout);
                toast.show();

                //return;
            }else{
                height_val = Float.parseFloat(et_height.getText().toString());
            }
```

After running the code, It work really good, shows the wanted Toast, then i correct the value and System said : "Unfortunately,...." .

Comment: Could you please be more specific, Thanks..

Comment: Could you post the entire code listing? I suspect your problem is caused by doing number comparisons with floats, although I can't be sure.

Comment: If are accepting floating point input you probably want to use BigDecimal. If you don't accept floating point your better off doing comparisons with integer numbers.

Comment: @Graham Thanks for your attention, The problem rise from that custom Toast also i applied what you mentioned (integer,double).